# How to find the licence of a font bundled to some software?

Tags: font-licensing

I have a font on my computer (specifically, Jenkins v2.0) that I obtained as part of a bigger software (specifically, Fontographer, formerly owned by Macromedia) and want to use it as a web font.

Unfortunately I cannot find a licence for this font and neither whom to get in contact with regarding use as a web font.

What ways (other than Googling) are there to obtain this information?

Comment: Was there any information that came along with the font file when downloading the font?

Comment: I edited your question a bit to make it more general and thus applicable to a larger audience. Please see whether everything is still according to you intentions.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, bundled fonts would have likely been listed within the license of the software it was bundled with.

Answer (score 0):

Some font formats allow to store metadata such as licences in the font file itself, however, in my experience, few programs actually show this data. However, most font editors (such as fontographer) should do so and FontForge (which is free) definetely does.

In the latter, use *Element → Font Info* and check *TTF Names* as well as *Copyright* under *PS Names.* In other programs, you have to find out yourself, but it should not be difficult to do so.